# $http in angularJS without controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Guys is it possible to get the $http ajax functions of angularJS without being in a controller?

Currently i have got factories, where i would like to have to database manipulations:

```
var Services = angular.module('App.Services', []);

Services.factory('Data', function () {

    var data;

    return {
        get:function (id) {
            return merchants[id];
        },
        getAll:function () {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/merchants'}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(arguments);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(arguments);
                });
            return data.slice(0);
        },
        add:function (_data) {
            _data.id = data.length;
            data.push(_data);
        },
        save:function (_data) {
            merchants[_data.id] = _data;
        },
        remove:function (_data) {
            delete merchants[_data.id];
        }
    }

});
```

How can i use $http now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any service within any service.
Just inject it like this:

```
Services.factory('Data', function ($http) {

   // use $http
});
```